# How to capture the ansible playbook output when creating ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible

I am creating Ec2 instance using Ansible playbook. Here I need to capture the output of created EC2 instance id, IPv4 etc. So how get the return values in command prompt and how to assign these values to one variable.

Comment: You should read the [registering variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#registering-variables) chapter, in Ansible documentation.

Comment: After you have the output in a registered variable, you can have a look into it as described under [`debug` module – Examples](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/debug_module.html#examples).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by β.εηοιτ.βε, registering variables can be helpful in your case.
Here is my test playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3
  tasks:
  - name: Launch ec2 instance
    amazon.aws.ec2_instance:
      region: us-east-2
      key_name: khaled
      security_group: launch-wizard-1
      instance_type: t2.micro
      image_id: ami-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
      wait: yes
      wait_timeout: 500
      tags:
        name: appservers
        os: ubuntu
      vpc_subnet_id: subnet-xxxxxxxx
      network:
        assign_public_ip: true
        delete_on_termination: true
      aws_access_key: "{{ aws_access_key|default(lookup('env', 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY')) }}"
      aws_secret_key: "{{ aws_secret_key|default(lookup('env', 'AWS_SECRET_KEY')) }}"
    register: ec2
    delegate_to: localhost

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ ec2 }}"
```

The output would be like:

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": {
        "changed": false,
        "changes": [],
        "deprecations": [],
        "failed": false,
        "instance_ids": [
            "i-xxxxxxxxxxxxx574"
        ],
        "instances": [
            {
                "ami_launch_index": 0,
                "architecture": "x86_64",
                "block_device_mappings": [
                    {
                        "device_name": "/dev/sda1",
                        "ebs": {
                            "attach_time": "2022-08-08T12:20:57+00:00",
                            "delete_on_termination": true,
                            "status": "attached",
                            "volume_id": "vol-xxxxxxxxxxxxxa8b"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "capacity_reservation_specification": {
                    "capacity_reservation_preference": "open"
                },
                "client_token": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                "cpu_options": {
                    "core_count": 1,
                    "threads_per_core": 1
                },
                "ebs_optimized": false,
                "ena_support": true,
                "enclave_options": {
                    "enabled": false
                },
                "hibernation_options": {
                    "configured": false
                },
                "hypervisor": "xen",
                "image_id": "ami-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                "instance_id": "i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                "instance_type": "t2.micro",
                "key_name": "khaled",
                "launch_time": "2022-08-08T12:20:56+00:00",
                "maintenance_options": {
                    "auto_recovery": "default"
                },
                "metadata_options": {
                    "http_endpoint": "enabled",
                    "http_protocol_ipv6": "disabled",
                    "http_put_response_hop_limit": 1,
                    "http_tokens": "optional",
                    "instance_metadata_tags": "disabled",
                    "state": "applied"
                },
                "monitoring": {
                    "state": "disabled"
                },
                "network_interfaces": [
                    {
                        "association": {
                            "ip_owner_id": "amazon",
                            "public_dns_name": "ec2-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxamazonaws.com",
                            "public_ip": "xx.xxx.xxx.xx"
                        },
                        "attachment": {
                            "attach_time": "2022-08-08T12:20:56+00:00",
                            "attachment_id": "eni-attach-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                            "delete_on_termination": true,
                            "device_index": 0,
                            "network_card_index": 0,
                            "status": "attached"
                        },
                        "description": "",
                        "groups": [
                            {
                                "group_id": "sg-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                                "group_name": "launch-wizard-1"
                            }
                        ],
                        "interface_type": "interface",
                        "ipv6_addresses": [],
                        "mac_address": "02:25:8d:2e:99:90",
                        "network_interface_id": "eni-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                        "owner_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
                        "private_dns_name": "ip-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.us-east-2.compute.internal",
                        "private_ip_address": "xx.xxx.xx.xx",
                        "private_ip_addresses": [
                            {
                                "association": {
                                    "ip_owner_id": "amazon",
                                    "public_dns_name": "ec2-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com",
                                    "public_ip": "xx.xxx.xxx.xx"
                                },
                                "primary": true,
                                "private_dns_name": "ip-xxxxxxxxxxxxx.us-east-2.compute.internal",
                                "private_ip_address": "xxx.xx.x.xx"
                            }
                        ],
                        "source_dest_check": true,
                        "status": "in-use",
                        "subnet_id": "subnet-xxxxxxxxx",
                        "vpc_id": "vpc-xxxxxxxxxxx"
                    }
                ],
                "placement": {
                    "availability_zone": "us-east-2a",
                    "group_name": "",
                    "tenancy": "default"
                },
                "platform_details": "Linux/UNIX",
                "private_dns_name": "ip-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.us-east-2.compute.internal",
                "private_dns_name_options": {
                    "enable_resource_name_dns_a_record": false,
                    "enable_resource_name_dns_aaaa_record": false,
                    "hostname_type": "ip-name"
                },
                "private_ip_address": "xxx.xx.x.xx",
                "product_codes": [],
                "public_dns_name": "ec2-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com",
                "public_ip_address": "xx.xx.xxx.xx",
                "root_device_name": "/dev/sda1",
                "root_device_type": "ebs",
                "security_groups": [
                    {
                        "group_id": "sg-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                        "group_name": "launch-wizard-1"
                    }
                ],
                "source_dest_check": true,
                "state": {
                    "code": 16,
                    "name": "running"
                },
                "state_transition_reason": "",
                "subnet_id": "subnet-xxxxxxxxxx",
                "tags": {
                    "name": "appservers",
                    "os": "ubuntu"
                },
                "usage_operation": "RunInstances",
                "usage_operation_update_time": "2022-08-08T12:20:56+00:00",
                "virtualization_type": "hvm",
                "vpc_id": "vpc-xxxxxxxxxx"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

You can then indicate any value you need and assign it/them to variable:

```yaml
  - name: Set ec2 facts
    set_fact:
      ec2inf: "{{ ec2.instances[0].instance_id }},{{ ec2.instances[0].public_ip_address }}"

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ ec2inf }}"
```

```yaml
TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx574,1x.1xx.xxx.205"
}
```

Comment: I am getting output but how to save this output in one file.
---
    - hosts: localhost
      gather_facts: false
      tasks:
      - name: Create AWS EC2 Instance
        amazon.aws.ec2:
          key_name: output
          instance_type: t2.micro
          image:*
          count: 1
          region: us-east-1
          volumes:
            - device_name: /dev/sdb
              volume_type: io1
              iops: 100
              volume_size: 4
        register: ec2
      - debug:
          msg: "{{ ec2 }}"
      - local_action: copy content= '{{ ec2 }}' dest=ec2output

Comment: `- local_action: copy content='{{ ec2 }}' dest=outputfile` That's right.

Comment: But it is saving empty txt file. Output is not stored that file?

Comment: Please use the module `amazon.aws.ec2_instance` instead of `amazon.aws.ec2`. ec2 is older, whereas ec2_instance is newer and behaves declarative like other Ansible modules. ec2 was meant to be deprecated at some point but due to enterprise dependencies.

Comment: I'm using this module amazon.aws.ec2_instance, still I'm getting same results.

Comment: @shevasaee could you please share you whole playbook.

Comment: - hosts: localhost
      gather_facts: false
      tasks:
      - name: Create AWS EC2 Instance
        amazon.aws.ec2_instance:
          key_name: output
          instance_type: t2.micro
          image_id: ami-***********
          wait: yes
          count: 1
          region: ap-south-1
          tags:
            name: appservers
            os: ubuntu
        register: ec2
        delegate_to: localhost
      - debug:
          msg: "{{ ec2 }}"
      - local_action: copy content= "{{ ec2 }}" dest=ec2output @Khaled

Comment: @shevasaee https://i.postimg.cc/wxCsDxsy/ec2.gif